# Avoid Google Spreadsheet to convert an XLSX file created by Open XML SDK to XLSM

Tags: google-sheets, openxml-sdk

I am using the [Open XML SDK 2.14.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/2.14.0) to create Excel files.
If I upload the XLSX file produced by Open XML SDK to Google Spreadsheet, it opens the file as an XLSX file but if I make any change in the spreadsheet then Google Spreadsheet changes the file type to XLSM.

The minimalistic code bellow ([found in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/structure-of-a-spreadsheetml-document#open-xml-sdk-code-example)) reproduces the issue I am having. It generate a `foo.xlsx` file in `C:\Temp`.

```cs
var filepath = @"C:\temp\foo.xlsx";

// Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
// By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

// Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

// Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

// Add Sheets to the Workbook.
Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

// Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet" };
sheets.Append(sheet);

workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

// Close the document.
spreadsheetDocument.Close();
```

If I upload the generated file to Google Spreadsheet, it shows this is an XLSX file.

[image]

But if I change anything in the workbook then Google Spreadsheet changes the file type to XLSM.

[image]

If I generate an empty workbook from MS Excel (Office 360) I don't have this issue : Google Spreadsheet will not change the file type if I change the data.

Why does Google Spreadsheet behave like this with XLSX file generated by Open XML SDK ?
What should I do to produce an XLSX file with the Open XML SDK that is not converted to XLSM by Google Spreadsheet ?

Comment: In your situation, was the mimeType changed before and after the edit your XLSX file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just ran the code provided, upload the file to Google Spreadsheet and made a change. I didn't explicitly change any mimeType. I am not sure to understand your question. How could I change the mimeType of the file and could I check if the mime type has changed ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your question 1 of `How could I change the mimeType of the file`, I cannot test your situation. But at Google Drive, Drive API might be able to change it. About your question 2 of `could I check if the mime type has changed ? `, as a simple way, you can see the mimeType of the file with "Try this API of "Files: get" of Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: Calling the Drive API needs to have a GCP account and configure an bunch of things and I am not familiar with GCP. I am not sure how that would help. I am only using Google Spreadsheet like a basic user. That said if I use the Chrome dev tool I can see that XLSX and XLSM file both have the same mime type : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet".

Comment: Thank you for replying. It seems that the mimeTypes of `XLSX` and `XLSM` are `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` and `application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12`. From your replying, it was found that the mimeType is not changed before and after the edit even when the showing extension is changed from `XLSX` to `XLSM`. From this situation, I thought that this might be a bug. So how about reporting your situation to [Google issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)? Because I couldn't find this issue in the issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I wasn't aware of the Google issue tracker. I'll report a bug and point it in a future comment. In the meantime I have also open an issue on the Open XML SDK GitHub : https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/1093

Comment: I double checked the mime type in the Chrome dev tools and I was wrong the XLSM file has the mime type you mentioned : `application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Anyway, I have reported the issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210875597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice person from the OfficeDev team found the solution : https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/1093

I am posting here the solution. It seems we need to call `spreadsheetDocument.AddCoreFilePropertiesPart();`

Thus my code looks like :

```cs
var filepath = @"C:\temp\foo.xlsx";

// Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
// By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
var coreFilePropPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddCoreFilePropertiesPart();

// With DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.14.0, AddCoreFilePropertiesPart includes an empty core.xml without a root which leads to an error when the generated file is opened in Excel
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(coreFilePropPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
  writer.WriteRaw("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp=\"https://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties\"></cp:coreProperties>");
  writer.Flush();
}

// Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

// Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

// Add Sheets to the Workbook.
Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

// Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet" };
sheets.Append(sheet);

workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

// Close the document.
spreadsheetDocument.Close();
```

And thus Google sheets stop changing from XLSX to XLSM !